# How to install xdebug in centos 7?

Tags: apache, centos7, xdebug, vps, php-5.6

I am using centos 7 & apache server, for remote debug purpose in VS Code how to install and configure xdebug in Live GoDaddy VPS server?

PHP version : 5.6

Answer (score 3):

if you have php7 in centos7 with webtactic and epel you can install xdebug with the following

yum install php70w-pecl-xdebug.x86_64

if you have epel and webtactic, but not php7 you can install xdebug with:

yum install php-xdebug

Now that xdebug is in your sytstem its time to confgure xdebug

```
open /etc/php.d/xdebug.ini in your favourite editor
add the following lines


#this line will be added automatically
zend_extension = /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/xxx/xdebug.so
#add the following
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log"
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_connect_back=on
xdebug.idekey=editor-xdebug
```

You can find the correct paths to the files needed if you have yum-utils installed and run

```
repoquery --list  php70w-pecl-xdebug

# the output is:
/etc/php-zts.d/xdebug.ini
/etc/php.d/xdebug.ini
/usr/bin/debugclient
/usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/xdebug.so
/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
/usr/share/doc/php70w-pecl-xdebug-2.4.1
/usr/share/doc/php70w-pecl-xdebug-2.4.1/CREDITS
/usr/share/doc/php70w-pecl-xdebug-2.4.1/LICENSE
/usr/share/doc/php70w-pecl-xdebug-2.4.1/README.rst
/var/lib/pear/pkgxml/xdebug.xml
```

You now need to restart httpd

```
service httpd restart
# or
systemctl restart httpd.service
```

Xdebug will now be up and running

If you are running with SELinux enforement on, then you can run this command to let xdebug out:

setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1

Eclipse

Inside eclipse, goto preferences > php > debuggers
change the debugger to xdebug
click configure
change the dropdown for “accept remote session (JIT)” to “any” or “prompt”
click ok
Firefox

Xdebug Helper is the best solution I have found for firefox – simply install the extension from here, navigate to the site you want to debug, and click the little green bug, select debug and reload your page to open in your editors debugger. You might need to add the key you added to your xdebug.ini in the previous steps.
Chrome

Xdebug Helper is the best solution I have found for chrome – simply install the extension from here, navigate to the site you want to debug, and click the little green bug, select debug and reload your page to open in your editors debugger. You might need to add the key you added to your xdebug.ini in the previous steps.

Comment: FYI - Still i am using PHP 5.6